# Keep on showing standard green icon in Android

Tags: android, icons

I've tried to put an ic_launcher icon in the drawable-xxhdpi dir , I've tried to delete this directory completely - the result is still the same - standard green icon on a full-HD screen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just accessing a different folder, like any of the other drawable folders? If you delete it, I'm sure that they just take it from a different folder.

Comment: I specified that - I deleted drawable-xxhdpi dir , others has a correct icon, but on the screen is a standard icon :(

Answer (score 0):

Android will use a default icon unless you specify a valid one in the manifest. Put your own icon in a drawable folder (ideally one the correct size in each one) and update your manifest's `<application>` element.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```